# Is 600kbps upload speed too slow for VOIP app?

Tags: voip, codec, bandwidth

I've built a voip app for iphone and android phone (audio only).  I've been testing the call quality.  I noticed that if a person has an upload speed of less than 600kbps, then his partner will have trouble hearing him clearly. His partner might hear lots of crackling, dropped sentences in speech, or nothing at all.

I am currently using GSM codec on my android, iphone and on my asterisk server.

**So my question is whether upload speeds of less than 600kpbs is generally considered too slow for VOIP calls?**

If so, is there anything I can do to reduce necessary bandwidth for call?  I could consider the G722 codec, but from what I remember, it doesn't offer significant bandwidth improvement compared to GSM

## Additional Notes

I used speedtest.net to inform me of my upload speed.  I'm not sure if that's reliable way to test speeds necessary for voip service.

Also, I'm using linphone core as my SIP library.

Comment: No, it's not too slow.  How much are you buffering?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm still relatively new to VOIP development, so I'm not too familiar with how to configure/evaluate buffering in my current app. Do you ahve any suggestions?  I'm using linphone core as my SIP library.